# What does "welch ein(e)" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does *welch ein(e)* mean? I've checked its meaning in [DWDS' dictionary](https://www.dwds.de/wb/welch%20ein) and also seen some examples; but I couldn't grasp its meaning and how to use it.

Could you give me a hand? I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: These are two separate words. Treating them as a single unit does not make sense. The meaning of these words depends on context.

Comment: @RHa https://www.dwds.de/wb/welch%20ein

Comment: This question can't be answered without context. Give some examples with sentences that contain these words.

Comment: I disagree with closing this. I don't understand how the meaning of the collocation "welch ein" would be context dependent.

Comment: @JonathanScholbach it is context dependent. "Welche (eine) Antwort Dir mehr zusagt, hängt von deren Inhalt ab". "Geh durch die Tür, welche eine grüne Markierung hat". "Welche eine (Farbe) hattest Du genommen?" etc. There definitely is not a single translation and it needs to be considered context dependent. Welch eine Aufregung! ;)

Comment: @Lazarus:  It is not clear to me what explanation is asked which goes beyond (more) examples than given in dwds. If you can elaborate?

Comment: @planetmaker Thanks! I edited the question to clarify what I think we are talking about here.